# How to hide products in frontend that are out of stock AND assigned to certain product categories?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to hide products in the WooCommerce frontend product listings that are out of stock AND assigned to certain product categories.

I already got it to remove out of stock products but I can't find a way to add a second condition to the already present "out of stock" one.

Here's what I've come up with so far (working):

```php
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'only_instock_products');
function only_instock_products($query) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => '_stock_status',
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            'value'     => 'instock'
        );
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I dont really understand. If its hiding - why do you need a second check?

Comment: @Mr. Jo I don't want all out of stock products to be hiding but only those that are out of stock AND are assigned to certain product categories.

Comment: Why not adding anther check to the meta_query array?

Comment: Well, I don't think you can check product categories via `meta_query`, can I? I guess I'd have to use `tax_query`, but not sure on how to combine `meta_query` and `tax_query` there.